# Remove url and leave only last part of it

Tags: php, preg-replace

I know is something pretty simple for someone who understand well [preg_replace](http://us.php.net/preg_replace) but I can't understand how to remove part of url. I have form where user should enter a `token`. The problem is that some users submitted whole url with `token` this kind of url

```
https://example.com/page/token

and 

http://example.com/page/token
```

I want when user submit the form to check if he/she inserted whole url and if is to remove everything and leave only `token` there

I've tried simple preg_replace like this

```
$result = preg_replace('https://example.com/page/', '', $str);
```

But error says

> Warning: preg_replace(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash

Then I've tried to escape those backslashes with `\` etc .. but same error occurred.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `$token = basename('https://example.com/page/token')`; - This will return the last part of the url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `preg_replace()` function should be like this:

```
$result = preg_replace('$(https|http)://example.com/page/$', '', $str);
```

You can use `$` as a delimiter.

Comment: Thanks. This seems to work perfectly.